pandas rolling mean and stacking previous values
I have a pandas dataframe of shape (2000,1) and I would like to compute rolling means but also keep the previous values as a lagged variable.
Assuming the Series:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

with a rolling window of 3, I would like:
1,2,3,mean(4,5,6)
4,5,6,mean(7,8,9)

I am able to use the rolling function:
train_ds=train_ds.var1.rolling(3).mean()

but this does not produce the above structure for me since I am unable to stack the previous values.

I'm not sure about your expected outcome, but you could reshape the series into a dataframe with three columns, then get the mean of the shifted rows in the fourth column:
n = 3
df = pd.DataFrame(s.to_numpy()[: len(s) - len(s) % n].reshape(-1, n))
df["mean"] = df.agg("mean", axis=1).shift(-1)

   0  1  2  mean
0  1  2  3   5.0
1  4  5  6   8.0
2  7  8  9   NaN

Or if you want a series of strings as the outcome:
s = df.astype(str).agg(", ".join, axis=1)

0    1, 2, 3, 5.0
1    4, 5, 6, 8.0
2    7, 8, 9, nan


I would have gone with a = s.values[:len(s)//3*3].reshape(-1, 3) ; out = pd.DataFrame(a[:-1]) ; out['mean'] = a[1:].mean(axis=1), if you keep shift, I'd suggest to shift after mean for efficiency ;)

@mozway That looks better. Good point about shift, thanks!

thank you @e-motta - not sure why I didnt think of reshaping it. thanks again.

A possible solution (mergesort is needed to guarantee that equal elements keep their relative position):
N = 3 # number of elements in each group

idx = len(df) % N # to remove the last block with less than N elements
d = df[N:-idx] 
# for each group of N elements, calculates the mean
d2 = (d.groupby( ((d.index % N) == 0).cumsum() )['var1'].mean() 
      # adjusts the indexes to have the positions where the means are to be
      # inserted
      .set_axis(d.index[d.index % N == N - 1] - N)) 

pd.concat([df[:-idx], d2]).sort_index(kind='mergesort')

Output:
   var1
0   1.0
1   2.0
2   3.0
2   5.0
3   4.0
4   5.0
5   6.0
5   8.0
6   7.0
7   8.0
8   9.0

